# How to prevent volume hijack on win 7

Tags: windows-7, audio

I sometimes play Prince of persia in my spare time. And recently the volume nob on my speaker has  worn out making the volume control a mess. If I touch it to adjust the volume it won't follow. Now my problem is:
When I play GAME(prince of persia) It takes over(hijacks) the volume setting, I have set the volume low using the volume control(located on right side of taskbar).

I want to prevent the game from overriding my current volume level.

### UPDATE

It seems my observation is **wrong**. The game didn't override the volume setting. The game sound appears **louder** than usual as compared to that while playing *songs* or *watching movies*(I use *iTunes* and *VLC media player* for that). It might be because of the **AutoVolumeLevelling or AVL** feature of the iTunes and VLC.
The game might not be using AVL and streaming audio on high(at the currently selected *max volume* setting in windows (audio)volume control).

Comment: You should be able to adjust the in-game volume settings.  The real solution is to replace the speaker if the volume control isn't an acceptable solution.

Comment: "Used to play"?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. I'm going to replace my speakers, sooner or later, but for now I just thought there might be some thing I can do to control the system volume.

Comment: @vvy - Yes.  You are already doing your the only solution by using the volume control within windows.

Comment: @Robusto grammar mistake ? I've edited.

Comment: Not a grammar mistake. But "used to play" means you don't play it anymore, in which case why would you need to fix the problem? Your edit fixed it.